# what most needed to be download in new api(21)?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have limited bandwidth and don't want to download all files of api 21 in sdk.
what files are really necessary?(no need to system images?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are minimum & necessary:

**1.** SDK Tools 24.0.2

**2.** SDK Platform-tools 21

**3.** SDK Build-tools 21.1.2

**4.** SDK Platform (API 21)